# Symfony2 Overriding Access Denied template

Tags: php, symfony

I'm stuck with overriding the Access Denied standard template.

I have read the whole documentation about overriding. Ive created

```
app\Resources\TwigBundle\views\Exception\error403.html.twig ,
error403.json.twig ,
accessdeniedexception.html.twig
```

Nothing is working for me actually.

I have read about "**only working in product environment**" aswell -> My product environment is activated but still not working. I have cleared cache multiple times by using

```
cache:clear
```

and deleting cache directories. Aswell i've used

```
assetic:dump.
```

Any ideas?

Greetings

UPDATE: I have created an exception_full.html.twig to override all templates for testing and it works! Is the name (error403.html.twig) wrong, for the access denied template?

Comment: clear cache use **"cache:clear"**

Comment: I wrote 'I have cleared cache multiple times'.

Comment: no problem =) any other ideas? :O

Comment: Ive read about creating a new controller -> but I dont need that much. Just wanna add my base layout to that template, and another text...

Comment: sorry，Never encounter this kind of situation before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved - didn't change from

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
```

to false

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', false);
```